# Wrapping Promise based JavaScript HTTP client with RxJs Observable

Tags: javascript, promise, observable, rxjs

I was thinking of using Observables to add .flatMapLatest() & .throttle() functionality to a Promise based HTTP client library (axios). But I'm not going to change the whole application to work with Observables, so I would need something like this:

Promise -> Observable -> Promise

Anyone managed to do something like this? None of the examples I've found do exactly that.

I know that RxJs provides a way to make an Observable from Promise and then convert it back to Promise, but haven't figured out how I could apply that to multiple Promises created by random subsequent HTTP client calls.

Answer (score 1):

Observables will automatically assimilate promises. You can just use them inside RxJS calls and it'll "just work":

```
myObservable.flatMap(x => somePromiseReturningFn("/api/" + x))
```

Will do exactly what you'd like it to.

Observables and promises mix and match nicely with `.toPromise` on observables and observables consuming promises automatically. You can safely mix and match them.

Just remember RxJS is not aware of promise library cancellation - so if you're relying on that you'd have to do it manually.

Comment: But how do I trigger new calls to that somePromiseReturningFn? I can't just create a new Observable every time. And I want to keep a function API, not to bind that Observable to some event.

Comment: I also assume that .flatMapLatest() would give me the latest Promise in order and not the latest Promise that resolved?

Comment: What about with the `.subscribe` API? Does that work nicely with promises? I could not get them to work well together...

Comment: `.subscribe` is what actually runs the observable.

Answer (score 0):

RXJS has a good pattern for this.

```
Observable.fromPromise(somePromiseReturningThing)
```

This is much better than the flatmap pattern above as the flatmap operates on error or legitimate return equally. Treat this obserable with your

```
Observable.fromPromise(aPromise)
  .map(..)
  .catch(..)
```

etc.