# Implement for-await-of statement in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, reactivex

I have the following statement:

```
 for await (const blob of client.list()) {
    console.log('\t', blob.name);
}
```

client.list() returns an async iterable iterator, and expects the use of [for await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) to resolve the promises. I would like to incorporate the code into an existing rxjs pipe that instantiates the client.

I looked everywhere and I couldn't figure out how to do so without resolving the promise inside the pipe rather than converting into observables.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"...expects the use of `for await...of` to resolve the promises..."* To *consume* the promises, not to *resolve* them. They're resolved by other code, not the loop above.

Comment: I think this is exactly what you want to do https://github.com/kgurkan/rxjs-async-iterator. Also discussion on RxJS github https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4002

Comment: @martin yeah I've seen that one, its what I'd needed to do the reverse of this. Going from RxJS into for-await-of.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As seen in the loop though, I am able to access the information from the promise; that is the 'blob' and its property 'name'. Therefore I think it does resolve the promise.

Comment: @MichaelMay - I'm afraid that simply isn't how promises work. :-) If you're given a promise instance, there's **nothing** you can do with it to resolve or reject it. Again, all the code does above is *consume* the promise -- that is, the code *responds* to the fact that the promise is resolved or rejected (by other code). It's just a terminology thing. *Resolving* a promise is the action of fulfilling it or making its fulfillment/rejection depend on another promise.

Comment: @MichaelMay What is the API expected by RxJS in this instance?

Comment: @Ben Its with [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?toc=/azure/javascript/toc.json&bc=/azure/javascript/breadcrumb/toc.json)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for explaining. I am not very familiar with promises, been using rxjs mostly.

Comment: What behavior do you want? Do you want the initialisation of the app to wait for processing of the client list before proceeding, and you want the clients to be processed in parallel?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916444/is-observable-and-promise-compatible-in-rxjs?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612746/wrapping-promise-based-javascript-http-client-with-rxjs-observable?rq=1

Comment: @Ben I just don't want to work with promise. I'm quite happy using Rx across various languages. Its not a duplicate of those questions. Simple fromPromise/from wasn't able to resolve asyncIterators. I wasn't sure what operators to pipe. The 2nd option in the answer below had what I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find an existing rxjs operator, but it doesn't seem too difficult to make your own. When integrating other APIs with observables you can interact with the API within the function passed to the observable constructor. This allows a lot of flexibility when triggering next/error/complete.

**Edit** - I've added a second option for doing this, using rxjs operators and avoiding explicitly calling next/error/complete.

```js
const {
  Observable,
  operators,
  from
} = rxjs;
const {take, takeWhile, expand, map, filter} = operators;

const asyncGen = async function*(x = -1) {
  while(x++ < 5) {
    yield x;
  }
};

const fromAsyncIter = iterable => new Observable(subscriber => {
  let unsubscribed = false;
  const iterate = async () => {
    try {
      for await (let n of iterable) {
        console.log('await', n);
        subscriber.next(n);
        if (unsubscribed) return;
      }
      subscriber.complete();
    } catch (e) {
      subscriber.error(e);
    }
  }
  iterate();
  return () => unsubscribed = true;
});

const fromAsyncIter2 = iterable =>
  from(iterable.next()).pipe(
    expand(() => iterable.next()),
    takeWhile(x => !x.done),
    map(x => x.value)
  );

// const source = fromAsyncIter(asyncGen()).pipe(take(2));
const source = fromAsyncIter2(asyncGen()).pipe(take(2));

source.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('next', x),
  error: e => console.error(e),
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think `asyncIterable` can be simplified as follows: `const asyncIterable = { async *[Symbol.asyncIterator](x = -1) { while(x++ < 5) yield x } }`

Comment: Maybe that's the only way to integrate with rxjs, but it isn't what I had in mind. Is there no way to do this without involving async ?

Comment: @MichaelMay so rather than using async/await, you want to call .then/.catch on the promise? May I ask why?

Comment: @NickL Your second snippet is exactly what I was after, and it works like a charm! I was looking for the use of "from", "of" and operators to hide the complexity of dealing with promise be it then/catch or await.